# Need a (XML, XSL)formatter for receiving file- PDF and HTML

Tags: xml

I need a (XML, XSL) formatter for PDF and HTML output files. Can someone help me with this? How can I recieve FO file?

Answer (score 0):

NFop or Apaceh Fop? What server side language are you programming in?